# count on one column and group by another column

Tags: sql, group-by, count

Suppose that we have a sample table

```
c1    |    c2
--------------
a     |     b
a     |     b
a     |     c
a     |     c
a     |     c
d     |     e
d     |     e
```

How can we turn this table into the following format

```
c1    |    c2   |     c3
--------------------------
a     |     b   |     2
a     |     c   |     3
d     |     e   |     2
```

where `c3` contains the count of `c2` based on distinct `c1` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a `group by` with two keys:

```
select c1, c2, count(*)
from t
group by c1, c2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was not familiar with `group by` with two keys.

Answer (score 2):

```
select c1, c2, count(*) as c3
from your_table
group by c1, c2
```